# Flex menu, first element on whole row after line break

Tags: css, menu, flexbox, responsive

Responsive flex menu (code bellow) is on smaller viewports arranged like this:

```
    |first item| |item| |item| |item| |item| |item| 
                    |last item|
```

Last item is on whole line in the middle. 
Is it possible to do this? :

```
                     |first item| 
    |item| |item| |item| |item| |item| |last item|
```

Looking for common solution. Menu can has any number of items.

```css
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {   
 background:#a0522d;
}
ul {
 border:5px solid #a0522d;
 display:flex;
 flex-wrap:wrap;
 max-width:75em;
 padding:0;
 margin:20px auto;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center
}
ul li {
 list-style:none;
 flex-grow:1;
}
ul li a         {
 line-height:1.5;
 padding:8px 16px;
 display:block;
 text-align:center;
 border-radius:0.313em;
 background:PaleGoldenrod;
 margin:2px;
}
.last, .almostlast {
 max-width:320px;
}
```

```html
 <ul>
     <li class="first"><a href="#">first item</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">second item</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">next item</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">pretty item</a></li>
     <li class="almostlast"><span><a href="#">item</a></span></li>
     <li class="last"><a href="#">last item</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You can use media queries?

Comment: Looking for common solution. Menu can has any number of items with different lenght of text.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to detect wrapping like that, especially because you only want the first item to be affected. Maybe css grid could work?

Comment: Trying "flex-wrap:wrap-reverse", one item is on the top. But the LAST, not FIRST. https://codepen.io/kelv/pen/GOLVmV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, by simply use `order` and a pseudo element, where the pseudo work as a delimiter, being 100% wide and take a row of its own.

With the `order` we then put the first item before the pseudo.

*Updated based on a comment at another answer*

- *Using a media query, so it only happens on narrower screens.*

Stack snippet

```css
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {   
 background:#a0522d;
}
ul {
 border:5px solid #a0522d;
 display:flex;
 flex-wrap:wrap;
 max-width:75em;
 padding:0;
 margin:20px auto;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center
}
ul li {
 list-style:none;
 flex-grow:1;
}

ul li a         {
 line-height:1.5;
 padding:8px 16px;
 display:block;
 text-align:center;
 border-radius:0.313em;
 background:PaleGoldenrod;
 margin:2px;
}
.last, .almostlast {
 max-width:320px;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  ul::before {
   content: ' ';                         /*  added  */
   width:100%;                           /*  added, fill width and push the rest down  */
}
  .first {
   order: -1;                            /*  added, move before pseudo  */
   flex-grow:0;                          /*  changed, to not fill width  */
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
     <li class="first"><a href="#">first item</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">second item</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">next item</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">pretty item</a></li>
     <li class="almostlast"><span><a href="#">item</a></span></li>
     <li class="last"><a href="#">last item</a></li>
</ul>
```

---

With this little trick the other pseudo can do other cool stuff

Stack snippet

```css
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {   
 background:#a0522d;
}
ul {
 border:5px solid #a0522d;
 display:flex;
 flex-wrap:wrap;
 max-width:75em;
 padding:0;
 margin:20px auto;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center
}
ul li {
 list-style:none;
 flex-grow:1;
}

ul li a         {
 line-height:1.5;
 padding:8px 16px;
 display:block;
 text-align:center;
 border-radius:0.313em;
 background:PaleGoldenrod;
 margin:2px;
}
.last, .almostlast {
 max-width:320px;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  ul::before {
   content: ' ';                         /*  added  */
   width:100%;                           /*  added, fill width and push the rest down  */
}
  .first {
   order: -1;                            /*  added, move before pseudo  */
   flex-grow:0;                          /*  changed, to not fill width  */
  }
}

@media (max-width: 700px) {
  ul::after {
   content: ' ';
   order: 1;
   width:100%;
  }
  ul li:nth-child(-n+3) {
   flex-grow:0;
  }
  ul li:nth-child(n+4) {
   order: 2;
   flex-grow:0;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
     <li class="first"><a href="#">first item</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">second item</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">next item</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">pretty item</a></li>
     <li class="almostlast"><span><a href="#">item</a></span></li>
     <li class="last"><a href="#">last item</a></li>
</ul>
```

---

*Update 2*

In addition to [Cons7an7ine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47672047/2827823)'s answer, by also combine `row-reverse wrap-reverse` with `order`, this can by done with existing markup, where one set enough `nth-child` to cover for *n* number of menu items.

```
ul {
 border:5px solid #a0522d;
 display:flex;
 flex-flow: row-reverse wrap-reverse;
 ...
}

ul li:nth-child(1)  { order: 100; }
ul li:nth-child(2)  { order:  99; }
ul li:nth-child(3)  { order:  98; }
...
```

[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/r2sfucsh/)

Stack snippet

```css
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {   
 background:#a0522d;
}
ul {
 border:5px solid #a0522d;
 display:flex;
 flex-flow: row-reverse wrap-reverse;
 max-width:75em;
 padding:0;
 margin:20px auto;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
}
ul li {
 list-style:none;
 flex-grow:1;
 white-space: nowrap;
}

ul li a         {
 line-height:1.5;
 padding:8px 16px;
 display:block;
 text-align:center;
 border-radius:0.313em;
 background:PaleGoldenrod;
 margin:2px;
}
.last, .almostlast {
 max-width:320px;
}

ul li:nth-child(1)  { order: 100; }
ul li:nth-child(2)  { order:  99; }
ul li:nth-child(3)  { order:  98; }
ul li:nth-child(4)  { order:  97; }
ul li:nth-child(5)  { order:  96; }
ul li:nth-child(6)  { order:  95; }
ul li:nth-child(7)  { order:  94; }
ul li:nth-child(8)  { order:  93; }
ul li:nth-child(9)  { order:  92; }
ul li:nth-child(10) { order:  91; }
```

```html
<ul>
     <li class="first"><a href="#">first item</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">second item</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">next item</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">pretty item</a></li>
     <li class="almostlast"><span><a href="#">item</a></span></li>
     <li class="last"><a href="#">last item</a></li>
</ul>
```

---

And if none of the above is a viable solution, with a script one can do this in almost any possible wished outcome.

Comment: This is solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is possible using pure CSS. But you can achieve this by using `flex-flow:row-reverse wrap-reverse;` then also make your `li` items in reverse.

```css
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {   
 background:#a0522d;
}
ul {
 border:5px solid #a0522d;
 display:flex;
 flex-flow:row-reverse wrap-reverse;
 max-width:75em;
 padding:0;
 margin:20px auto;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center
}
ul li {
 list-style:none;
 flex-grow:1;
}
ul li a         {
 line-height:1.5;
 padding:8px 16px;
 display:block;
 text-align:center;
 border-radius:0.313em;
 background:PaleGoldenrod;
 margin:2px;
}
.last, .almostlast {
 max-width:320px;
}
```

```html
 <ul>
     <li class="last"><a href="#">last item</a></li>
     <li class="almostlast"><span><a href="#">item</a></span></li>
     <li><a href="#">pretty item</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">next item</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">second item</a></li>
     <li class="first"><a href="#">first item</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Nice.
But, I can not change html code. First LI have to be Site name :(.

Answer (score 0):

## Yes.

Set the first `li` to 100% width and the set the link inside to a centered in that `li`.

```
  .first {
    flex: 0 0 100%;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
  }
```

Result:

[image]

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  background: #a0522d;
}

ul {
  border: 5px solid #a0522d;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: 75em;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 20px auto;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

ul li a {
  line-height: 1.5;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 0.313em;
  background: PaleGoldenrod;
  margin: 2px;
}

.last,
.almostlast {
  max-width: 320px;
}

.first {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="first"><a href="#">first item</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">second item</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">next item</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">pretty item</a></li>
  <li class="almostlast"><span><a href="#">item</a></span></li>
  <li class="last"><a href="#">last item</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Nice. 
But, for wide viewport should be all items together in one row :(.

Comment: Sure, but you can do that with a media query. https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/BmeyeQ  This jsut shows the basic technique